# Optimizing trimmed K-means for clustering of 2D data with many outliers? Better approach?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I have the following type of data/plot

[image]

Just looking at the datapoints alone it's pretty much impossible to judge where the peaks should be, but if drawn with 2D density smoothing in ggplot I get these really nice peaks, where I can visually count ~10 groups of points that I'd like to find. The exact number of "valid groups" is of course up for discussion.

Data here:
https://pastebin.com/5wquw7UF

```
library(ggplot2)
library(colorRamps)
library(tclust)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    stat_density2d(geom = "raster",
                   aes(fill = ..density..),
                   contour = FALSE) +
    geom_point(col = "white", alpha = 0.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       limits = c(0,1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       limits = c(0,1)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 11, base_family = "Helvetica") +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7),
          legend.key.height = unit(2.5,"line"),
          legend.key.width = unit(1, "line")) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Density",
                         colours = matlab.like(1000))
```

I've looked into trimmed clustering, with the package `tclust`. By fiddling around with the data I've been able to come up with the below. However, no matter how much I fiddle around with the parameters I can't seem to get groups that are as "tight" as I visually feel like I see. Especially group 5 seems to sneak its way into places it doesn't belong. Group 10 is also a bit odd, but isolated enough to discard afterwards.

Is there a way better method for this, or is it simply me not understanding how to set the parameters correctly?

```
set.seed(2)

trimmed_cluster <- tclust(
    x = df,
    k = 10, # 9
    alpha = 0.1, # 0.1
    drop.empty.clust = FALSE,
    equal.weights = TRUE,
    restr = c("sigma", "eigen"), # sigma
    restr.fact = 1
)

df$cluster <- trimmed_cluster$cluster

trimmed_cluster_centers <- data.frame(t(trimmed_cluster$centers))

df_clustered <- subset(df, cluster != 0)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    stat_density2d(geom = "raster",
                   aes(fill = ..density..),
                   contour = FALSE) +
    geom_point(data = df_clustered, aes(x = x, y = y, col = as.factor(cluster))) +
    geom_text(data = trimmed_cluster_centers,
              aes(x = x, y = y, label = as.character(1:length(trimmed_cluster_centers$x))),
              size = 5,
              fontface = "bold",
              col = "yellow2") +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       limits = c(0,1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       limits = c(0,1)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 11, base_family = "Helvetica") +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7),
          legend.key.height = unit(0.8,"line"),
          legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "line")) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Density",
                         colours = matlab.like(1000)) +
        scale_color_brewer(name = "cluster ID",
                   type = "qual",
                   palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

Comment: What about the classic DBSCAN algorithm for **density based** clustering?

Comment: This is *perfect* and I almost feel stupid for asking now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of k-means, I suggest that you use [DBSCAN density-based clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

It is a well-tested and often used clustering algorithm to find **density-connected components** of arbitary shape.

The N in the name stands for noise, as the algorithm can "ignore" points that do not belong to any cluster (because of low density). It is fairly robust to noise, which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for peaks in the density, the means shift algorithm may be helpful.   As with any clustering algorithm, you may want to spend some time tuning the parameters, but I got something that seems plausible pretty quickly.

```
library(LPCM)   
MS7 = ms(df, 0.07)
MS7$cluster.center
        [,1]       [,2]
1 0.55790817 0.46878846
2 0.42916901 0.60982702
3 0.04142821 0.63190748
4 0.58098385 0.03693459
5 0.01561478 0.19987934
6 0.18271326 0.01630580
7 0.80381893 0.65499869
8 0.59797721 0.88041362
9 0.86784436 0.95078057
```

[image: Results of Mean shift]

Comment: I love the lot.  There is some room for improvement in the line-trajectories, but it is beautiful.

Comment: @EngrStudent-ReinstateMonica  - yes. There is another library (MeanShift) that has an implementation of mean shift, but I use tis one because of the beautiful plots. ☺

Comment: is there a way to use something like matlab::jet.colors with it?  When I have ~30 clusters, the colors are ambiguous. Is there a way to order colors vs cluster centers to improve contrast? When I get "n" adjacent version of yellow (poor contrast) lines, the plot misses out on some utility.  Maybe I should submit as a new question.